# Instant mirror-ing between two <div>

Tags: image, drag, mirror

When I drag an image into a div box, the div box next to it should immediately mirror it and contain the image as well.

However if you look at the Fiddle example below, when I drag the image into the pink box, the blue box does not mirror the pink box and contain the image as well.

Is there a way to allow the blue box to immediately mirror the content in the pink box whenever an image is dragged into it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjjtpg20/1/

```
see JSFiddle
```